# Spring TestRestTemplate not autowiring correctly

Tags: java, spring, junit

I'm currently using Spring Boot 1.5.4 alongside Junit 5 and Java 8.

I want to setup integration tests on multiple entries that are stored in a csv file using Junit's ParameterizedTest.

Here is the code:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class MatchingIT {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate template;

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource(names = "vehicles")
    void nonRegressionTests(EDIVehicle vehicle) {
        ResponseEntity<Vehicle> v = template.getForEntity("/match/" + vehicule.getId(), Vehicle.class);
        Assert.assertNotNull(v);
    }

    private static Stream<EDIVehicle> vehicles() throws IOException {
        InputStream is = new ClassPathResource("/entries.csv").getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        return br.lines().map(toVehicle);
    }

    private static Function<String, EDIVehicle> toVehicle = (line) -> {
        String[] p = line.split("\\|");
        return new EDIVehicle(p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5], p[6], p[7], p[8], p[9], p[10], p[11], p[12]);
    };
}
```

I know from the documentation that:

> If you are using the @SpringBootTest annotation, a TestRestTemplate is automatically available and can be @Autowired into your test.

The thing is that I do use the SpringBootTest annotation but when I run the tests, the TestRestTemplate is constantly null. Maybe I missed something.

EDIT: I do have the exact same problem while adding @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) annotation

Comment: Are you using JUnit 5? I don't think there is first class support from Spring Boot for JUnit 5 yet. There is an extension that may help you: https://github.com/sbrannen/spring-test-junit5

Comment: Can you check from which package you imported `TestRestTemplate`?
`org.springframework.boot.test.web.client` or `org.springframework.boot.test` ?

Comment: @harshavmb I'm using org.springframework.boot.test.web.client and not the deprecated one.

Comment: @LucasP I'l using JUnit 5 yes. I'll try with JUnit 4 to make sure the problem doesn't come from the JUnit version.

Comment: @Lucas I fixed my issue by using the dependency you mentioned. Thx!
The thing is, my tests are not ran by maven when doing a 'mvn clean install'

Comment: EDIT: It works fine by adding the '@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)' annotation with the right dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using the dependency from the following repo: [github.com/sbrannen/spring-test-junit5](http://github.com/sbrannen/spring-test-junit5)  as mentioned @LucasP

Since there is no first class support for JUnit 5 in Spring 4.3 and below it helped me autowiring correctly the Spring TestRestTemplate by using `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` on my test class.

Next step would be to directly use Spring Boot 2.0 for a better support of JUnit 5.

Answer (score 1):

`@SpringBootTest` is not compleatelly compatible with JUnit 5. However you can workaround this by using the next test declaration:

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
class MatchingIT {...}
```

*Note:* You have to upgrade your `spring-boot-starter-test` version to `2.0.0.M1` to be able to use `org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension` (the simplest way would be using [start.spring.io](http://start.spring.io/) for generating 2.0.0.M1-dependent project and taking needed maven/gradle dependencies from there).

Comment: I'm not sure that I already want to use Spring 5 in my project. I might try if I can't find any other solution and I'll come back to you.

Comment: You don't need to use Spring 5 for whole project. You need it only in tests. You're already using Junit 5 which is not released yet - adding one more unreleased test dependency should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and also make sure your class which initialize the context (usually the one that contains the main method) have a `@SpringBootApplication` annotation (else `@SpringBootTest` doesn't find the context to load for the test.

Comment: As I said to David Florez I do have the exact same problem even with the @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) annotation. I'm looking into contexts.

Comment: I think @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) would be one of possible solution to your Problem. The difference between SpringRunner and SpringBootTest is specified in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58901288/springrunner-vs-springboottest