# SpringRunner vs SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

In unit test, what are the differences between `@Runwith(SpringRunner.class)` & `@SpringBootTest`?

Can you explain to me the use cases of each one?

Comment: Have you read any of the various documentation? What's still unclear?

Comment: The obvious difference is Spring test vs Spring boot test, but it's very broad question

Comment: I would understand when should I use @SpringBootTest in addition of SpringRunner.

Comment: RunWith is no longer required as of JUnit 5 and can be dropped from your unit test code.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

**@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) :** You need this annotation to just enable spring boot features like `@Autowire`, `@MockBean` etc.. during junit testing

> is used to provide a bridge between Spring Boot test features and JUnit. Whenever we are using any Spring Boot testing features in our JUnit tests, this annotation will be required.

**@SpringBootTest :** This annotation is used to load complete application context for end to end integration testing

> The @SpringBootTest annotation can be used when we need to bootstrap the entire container. The annotation works by creating the ApplicationContext that will be utilized in our tests.

Here is the article with clear examples on both scenarios [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing)

Comment: The Baeldung link is one of the best ones explaining the concept, however its dependencies are not correct and hence not working. Although I included all the dependencies in my pom, I get "Class<SpringRunner> cannot be resolved to a type".

Answer (score 58):

@RunWith is an old annotation from JUnit 4 to use test runners. If you're using JUnit 5 (Jupiter), you should use @ExtendWith to use JUnit extensions

See
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-testing

"If you are using JUnit 4, don’t forget to also add @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) to your test, otherwise the annotations will be ignored. If you are using JUnit 5, there’s no need to add the equivalent @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) as @SpringBootTest and the other @…Test annotations are already annotated with it.

Comment: I just dropped the RunWith annotation when I converted to JUnit 5. Seems to be no need to use ExtendWith either as your quote from the Spring docs makes clear.

Answer (score 16):

From [spring.io](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4) :

> `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` tells JUnit to run using Spring’s testing
>   support. `SpringRunner` is the new name for `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`,
>   it’s just a bit easier on the eye.
>
> `@SpringBootTest` is saying “bootstrap with Spring Boot’s support” (e.g.
>   load `application.properties` and give me all the Spring Boot goodness)

So if you don't need everything that Spring Boot loads for your integration test, you may not need `@SpringBootTest`