# Unit testing with @SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing

Currently a colleague is arguing that

My test written as below:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = App.class)
public class ServiceTest {

    private Integer a;
    private String str;


    @Before
    public void prepareTestData() {
       //
    }

    @Test
    public void test_scenario_1() {
        //
    } 
}
```

is not a unit test for my Service class because I am pulling through all the application using

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = App.class)
```

I understand that unit tests should be testing the service code in complete isolation, but I am not having a autowire service depdency injection of any sort in my test code.

My question is what is the @SpringBootTest(classes = App.class) annotation doing behind the scenes is it really bootstraping the complete application before the test code is run?

Is the test above really an integration test?

Comment: yes `@SpringBootTest` will load the application context. If you want unit testing for service layer you use `SpringRunner` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58901288/springrunner-vs-springboottest

Comment: Hum nice, so actually for my test I don't need the SpringBootTest annotation at all?

Comment: For unit testing you don't need it, But for integration testing `@SpringBootTest` is needed

Comment: if you want to test the services only, use a mocking framework