# SpringBoot application not able to load test properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-boot-test

I'm having issues, while loading my spring boot application test properties.I have my application.properties file included under src/test/resources/ but when I was running test cases its failing because it was not able to load application context. Here is my test class looks like

```
@SpringBootTest
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, controlledShutdown = true)
@Import(KafkaTestConfiguration.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = IntegrationAutoConfiguration.class)
public class DeadLetterPropertiesTest {

    @Autowired
    DeadLetterProperties deadLetterProperties;

    @Value("errorqueue")
    private String deadLetterQueueName;

    @Test
    public void queueNameTest() {
 assertEquals(deadLetterQueueName,deadLetterProperties.getQueueName());
}
}
```

Here is the stacktrace looks like:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException  at 
com.test.DeadLetterPropertiesTest.queueNameTest(DeadLetterPropertiesTest.java:47)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)   at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)   at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)    at 
org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)    at 
org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)     at 
org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)  at 
    org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)   at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)   at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)     at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace confirms that during test the creation of the application context is failing. It might be because of several reasons of which one might be , not able to read values from `application.properties`. There are a couple of issues that I noticed in your code.In your code you can remove the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation if you are using the `@SpringBootTest` annotation as per the documentation :

> Spring Boot provides a @SpringBootTest annotation which can be used as
>   an alternative to the standard spring-test @ContextConfiguration
>   annotation when you need Spring Boot features. The annotation works by
>   creating the ApplicationContext used in your tests via
>   SpringApplication.

- You can provide you mock bean configurations for your test using the
  annotation `@TestConfiguration` instead.You should also exclude the
  normal configuration classes as this will create conflict if you are
  providing a separate test configuration for the same beans.
- Also, if you have your `application.properties` with the test values
  under `src/test/resources` then there is no need for you to specify
  the path using `@TestPropertySource` as the file will be
  automatically taken up by springboot during test.
- Also do not use the annotation `@SpringBootTest` and `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` togethor. These are both different annotations for different use cases. If you do not understand what to use when use the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58901288/springrunner-vs-springboottest)

Official [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html)

For further analysis correct your code then run again and if still the error persists please share the complete stacktrace .

Comment: I have updated the post with the new changes i have made. Now I'm getting null pointer exception.

Comment: @TechGeek you getting null pointer exception on `DeadLetterPropertiesTest.java:47` which is the `deadLetterProperties.getQueueName()` getter method . which means the getter is returning null. Could you share the code for the class so that we may analyze more.