# Bean autowired as null for integration test using spring boot 2.1.15.RELEASE(junit 4)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

Following is my code that is causing issue and it is using spring-boot-starter-parent 2.1.15.RELEASE(this version has junit 4 in it).In  this context,summary,title all beans are injected as null.

```
import com.example.demo.helpers.Subtitle;
import com.example.demo.helpers.Summary;
import com.example.demo.helpers.Title;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;

@SpringBootTest(classes = {Summary.class, Title.class, Subtitle.class},webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = org.springframework.boot.test.context.ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;  // null

    @Autowired
    Summary summary;    // null

    @Autowired
    Title title;        // null

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        System.out.println("executed testcase..");
    }
}
```

However when i upgrade the version of spring-boot-starter-parent to 2.6.1(it has junit 5 in it).All autowired beans are getting injected properly.

However there is certain limitation that i can not upgrade version as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
```

Otherwise Autowired doesn't work on JUnit 4

see [SpringRunner vs SpringBootTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58901288/springrunner-vs-springboottest)

Comment: Thanks Johannes.Post adding above annotation, all beans got autowired.