# Unit Test Elasticsearch Repository Null Values

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, elasticsearch

In my Test class, I am trying to send a request to an API and compare the results with the ones that are sent from Springboot using elastic search data.

I am able to send the request via WebClient. However, the Service and Repository objects are always null. Any help would be great. Thanks

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
class MyTest {
    
      @Autowired
      private ESService esService; //this is null

      @Autowired
      private OtherRepository otherRepo; //this is null

      @Test
      private void testFunction(){
          TestObject Object = esService.doSomething();
          double value = new TestObject(otherRepo).getValue();
   }
}
```

```
    @Service
    public interface ESService{
        TestObject doSomething();
    }
```

```
@Service
public class ESServiceImpl implements ESService{
    
        @Autowired
        private ESRepository esRepository;
        
        TestObject doSomething(){
          return esRepository.doSomething();
      }
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface ESRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<QueryResponse, String>, ESRepositoryCustom {
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.8.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: you are missing `@SpringBootTest`

Comment: But according to this post, @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) should be enough for @Autowired.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58901288/springrunner-vs-springboottest